# Parsing Ints to Strings from Scanner in Try Catch

Tags: java

I've been given a task that I have to create a Shopping List program. I've done this in Python, and it was relatively straight forward. However, in Java I've hit a bit of a roadblock.

These are my variables, I am aware of the issues with using statics in this way and that it would be best to avoid doing it.

```
private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
private static String list_add = "string"; //"string" is just a place holder
private static ArrayList listFull = new ArrayList();
private static ArrayList listPos = new ArrayList();
private static int userIn = 1; //1 is also being used as place holder
```

Which I use in:

```
private static void userInput() {
    boolean isValid = false;

    while (!isValid) {
        isValid = true;
        try {
            userIn=Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("That's not a valid number!");
            isValid = false;
        }
    }

}
```

The reasoning behind doing it this way is the less one needs to type the quicker the task can be completed. Which was working as nice philosophy up until I tried this. My previous attempt to solve this problem gave an infinite loop, and the second solution that came to mind returned a `StackOverflowError`. When I asked about avoiding the infinite loop, I was directed to another question ([Endless loop while using "try and catch " block inside a "while loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43237705/9887372)) which I did not believe helpful to begin with, however found that it was (Thank you whoever marked that). I didn't get this solution to work, however, and I cannot see where I went wrong.

After trying different inputs to see if their was one specific type that killed it, these were the errors I received:

Test Case "strin":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "strin"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at DebuggingMethods.AllIn(DebuggingMethods.java:17)
    at DebuggingMethods.Menu(DebuggingMethods.java:33)
    at DebuggingMethods.main(DebuggingMethods.java:58)
```

Test Case "Ten":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Ten"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at DebuggingMethods.AllIn(DebuggingMethods.java:17)
    at DebuggingMethods.Menu(DebuggingMethods.java:33)
    at DebuggingMethods.main(DebuggingMethods.java:58)
```

Test Case int(10):

Which ran with the anticipated outcome.

I had thought that I was missing a module, so I did `import java.lang.*;` which did not change the error. If someone has a solution, please help me out. I can't find a question that already posted that explains what I am doing wrong. When I pulled it out of the Try-Catch it was working kind of.

---

Full Piece

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;

public class TestOne {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static String list_add = "string";
    private static ArrayList listFull = new ArrayList();
    private static ArrayList listPos = new ArrayList();
    private static int userIn = 1;

    private static void userInput() {
        boolean isValid = false;

        while (!isValid) {
            isValid = true;
            try {
                userIn=Integer.parseInt(input.next());
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("That's not a valid number!");
                isValid = false;
            }
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //titleMain();
        userInput(); // For the sake of demonstration


    }

}
```

Comment: WHat is in input.next()?

Comment: It should be a String, which should be parsed to an int. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be happening, so I don't really know

Comment: What do you actually want to do can you please explain? Because I could not find any user input in program and no declaration of userin as well.

Comment: menuSelect is specified as an int variable, and the user input is comes from `menuSelect=Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());`. All I am trying to do is allow for a user to input a string equivalent to the number, which can be done. I am also trying to get my try-catch to prompt the user to retry if the input is invalid and unable to be used as an int.

Comment: Please post a valid [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had the right document, apparently I was working out of the wrong one. I've updated it.

Comment: userIn=Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()); for parsing into integer

Comment: You never call `userInput()` for one

Comment: I just tried that, it gave me the same thing as `.next()`.

Comment: Now you're changing code willy-nilly. Please ask a stable question with stable tested code.

Comment: I don't call it because I am getting the errors out of the way before I bother trying to implement it fully. And its being debugged as in another file, that's where it will end up once I have solved my issues. If all else fails, I can scrap this idea and do it relatively normally.

Comment: I have got the correct version up now, the last one was from a previous document that I mistook for the one I am trying to get working.

Comment: You're catching the wrong exception.

Comment: Figured that out about 12 minutes ago, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your exceptions mixed up.  You're catching an `InputMismatchException`, which is what `input.nextInt()` would have thrown if the input were invalid.  But you're actually using `Integer.parseInt` to parse the input, which throws `NumberFormatException` in case of invalid input.  And since `NumberFormatException` isn't a subclass of `InputMismatchException`, it isn't caught and you end up dying with a stack trace.

You don't actually need to do anything with exception at all here.  The `Scanner` can *tell you* if the next input is a valid integer or not and you can then *actively* decide what do about it.  Think along these lines:

```
Scanner sc;
//...
System.out.println("Please enter a number");
while (!sc.hasNextInt()){
    sc.nextLine();  // throw away the bad input
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid number");
}
int theNum = sc.nextInt();
```