# Exeptions and parseInt

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, parseint

Why is it that my first method "inputNumber" returns infinite output "this is not a valid number" 
while the second method returns to the question "type a valid number: "

i don't understand why the method with the parseInt doesn't do the same thing...
they both throw an exception and both execute the "catch".

here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("you typed the number: " + inputNumber(input));

}

public static int inputNumber(Scanner input) {
    int num = 0;
    while (num == 0) {
        System.out.print("Type a number: ");
        try {
            return input.nextInt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("this is not a valid number");
        }
    }
    return num;
}

public int readNumber(Scanner input) {
    boolean running = true;
    while (running) {
        System.out.print("Write a number: ");

        try {
            int num = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
            return num;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("this is not a valid number");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Because `input.next()` doesn't consume the entire line and makes the loop infinite. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50672003/parsing-ints-to-strings-from-scanner-in-try-catch

Comment: Hint: catching ALL kinds of exception, to then just print some hardcoded string ... bad idea. Print the exception itself, to get a clue what **really** went wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please make few changes:
1. No need of num variable in inputNumber() method,
2. Make readNumber() method static.
```

Also you can try this logic for inputNumber() method.

```
public static int inputNumber(Scanner input) {
   System.out.print("Type a number: ");
    try {
        return input.nextInt();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("this is not a valid number");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well thanks for checking my code and suggestions. but i am not really looking for an edit in my code. i want to know why the parseInt exception is different from any other exception, and why it makes it so that the while loop is not in an infinite loop?